# nodeJS await to move files then compress images

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote this code that checks image files sizes in a folder, if the file are bigger than 30000 bytes then moves to a temporary folder called 'before-compress'. The compressImages() function iterates over the 'before-compress' folder and returns the compressed images to the original folder. My question is: How can i await the process of move the exceeded size files and then call the compressImage() function?, as you can see in the code i handle this with a setTimeout once the forEach reaches the last item. Thanks in advance.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const imagemin = require("imagemin");
const imageminMozjpeg = require("imagemin-mozjpeg");
const imageminPngquant = require("imagemin-pngquant");
const imageminGifsicle = require('imagemin-gifsicle');


const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads');

fs.readdir(`${directoryPath}/products`, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    files.forEach(function (file) {      
        console.log(`File: ${file} - Size: ${getFilesizeInBytes(file)} bytes`); 
        if(getFilesizeInBytes(file) > 30000){
            moveFile(file)
        }

        if(files.indexOf(file) == files.length - 1){
            //console.log('last index');
            setTimeout(() => compressImages(), 4000);
        }
    });
});

function getFilesizeInBytes(fileName) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(`${directoryPath}/products/${fileName}`);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}

function moveFile(file){
    var oldPath = `${directoryPath}/products/${file}`;
    var newPath = `${directoryPath}/before-compress/${file}`;

    fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`File ${file} moved!`);
    })
}



function compressImages(){

    fs.readdir(`${directoryPath}/before-compress`, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        } 
        files.forEach(function (file) {      
            console.log(`File to compress: ${file}`);
            let fileExt = file.split('.')[1];

            let compressPlugin = fileExt == 'jpg' || fileExt == 'jpeg' ? imageminMozjpeg({quality: 40}) : 
            fileExt == 'png' ? imageminPngquant({quality: [0.5, 0.6]}) : 
            fileExt == 'gif' ? imageminGifsicle() : 0;
        
            (async () => {
                const files = await imagemin([`./uploads/before-compress/${file}`], {
                destination: './uploads/products',
                plugins: [ compressPlugin ]
                });
                fs.unlink(`${directoryPath}/before-compress/${file}`, err => err ? console.log(err) : 0);
            })();   
                  
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: If you want to use `await`, convert *everything* to  promises (instead of callbacks), and don't use `forEach`.

Comment: Compressing files could take a lot of time.... is there any call back executed just after the compressing process is over?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga the compressing process runs with async await, there's not problem in that, the problem here is to fire compressImages() function once the exceeded size files are in the before-compress folder.

Comment: Use `fs.renameSync` or convert `moveFile` to return a Promise, then use `await` keyword when executing it.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of code would become much more readable if you would convert all the functions from using callbacks to using async.

If you want to keep using callbacks however, there are two options:

- Make `moveFile()` to use `fs.renameSync()` instead of `fs.rename()`. Normally I would advise against that, but since you are already using `fs.statSync()` and I suppose you run this as a script with nothing in parallel, maybe that would be an acceptable solution.
- Or make `moveFile()` accept a callback:

```js
function moveFile(file, callback){
    // [...]
    fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, callback)
}
```

Now you can use this callback to detect when the file has been moved, for example like this:

```js
    // [...]
    var done = 0;
    var error = false;
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        if(error) return;
        if(getFilesizeInBytes(file) > 30000){
            moveFile(file, function(err) {
                if (err) { console.log(err); error = true; }
                done++;
            });
        } else {
            done++;
        }

        if(done == files.length) {
            compressImages(), 4000);
        }
    });
});
```